# Email is not working in Joomla Site [SMTP]

Tags: php, linux, joomla

I'm getting an error like :

> Notice
>       SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
>       ×
>       Error
>       Test mail could not be sent.

My Email Setting as below,

[image: Email Configuration]

I'm able to telnet my email host. Application is hosted in Linux Server.

Comment: Check the smtp port is open or not. Ask your host provider about SMTP ports. Some host providers block some ports. They will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi if you are using Gmail account

refer https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854

if any other smtp service ask your host provider